# Get the next 500 "free" numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, integer

I have an array with numbers, representing used locations. I want to get the first 500 unused numbers from number 1 up to any number.

So for example, my array contains the following numbers: 1,2,5,6,8,9

Based on that array, I would like to have a new array containing the following numbers: 3,4,7,10,11,12,13,14....500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507

Is there any more efficient way than to have a loop with an increasing number, checking if that number is contained by the default array, if not put that in the new array, check if the new array has 500 values and then break from the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a `Location` object that contains an `Id` property and an `IsUsed` property?  That way you can filter out via LINQ anything that is `~IsUsed`

Comment: Hint: Suppose you were writing the C standard library -- someone had to!  How would you implement `malloc` efficiently? Because your problem is very similar to malloc: you have a bunch of already-used memory, someone asks you for 500 more contiguous bytes, and you've got to provide them. You can do it much more efficiently than having an array that has a number in it for every byte allocated.

Comment: Second hint: Malloc doesn't use arrays. Your algorithm cannot be made efficient because you've chosen the wrong data structure. Choose a data structure other than an array to represent your free/busy lists.

Comment: @EricLippert: Maybe that data structured has not been chosen by the OP but it was a requirement. In this case you can generate your own optimal data structure from that, before starting to determine the required 500 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest implementing *generator*:

```
// source should be sorted
private static IEnumerable<int> Free(IEnumerable<int> source) {
  int last = 0;
  bool first = true;

  foreach (var item in source) {
    if (first) 
      first = false;
    else 
      for (int i = last + 1; i < item; ++i) // <- Hole 
        yield return i;

    last = item;
  }

  // The array exhausted
  for (int i = last + 1; ; ++i)
    yield return i;
}
```

And then generate as many items as you want with a help of *Linq*

```
int[] used = new[] { 1,2,5,6,8,9};

int[] free = Free(used)
  .Take(501) // <- if you want 507 being the last item you have to take 501 items
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", free));
```

Outcome:

```
3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 505, 506, 507
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = list.Except(usedList).Take(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] GetMissingNumbers(int[] provided, int maxLength)
{
    var numbersBeyondEndOfProvidedRange = Enumerable.Range(1, provided.Length + maxLength);
    return numbersBeyondEndOfProvidedRange.Except(provided).Take(maxLength).ToArray();
}
```

Given your input and an output of 500 numbers, the last number is 506, not 507.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetRange method of IEnumerable collections

Please visit the link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx